# Is there a way to invoke Perl debugger by some environment variables?

Tags: perl

We all know that `perl5db.pl` can be invoked by `perl -d`,but is there a way to invoke the debugger by some environment variables instead of a command line option?

Comment: apparently, there's none. Why do you need that? Providing more context could lead to new ideas...

Comment: @new_perl, what was the context in which you needed an environment variable to invoke debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the PERL5OPT environment variable to '-d':

```
$ export PERL5OPT=-d
$ ./test.pl 

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.3
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

main::(./test.pl:3):    print "Hello\n";
  DB<1> r
Hello
```

Comment: Worth noting is that this environment variable modifies the perl command line arguments. I'm not sure it's going to do anything useful in a mod_perl environment.